# Google Scripts - Function Error with Time Trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

This function/trigger combo is intended to keep a log of live data on a daily basis. The intent is that N2:P2 get pasted as values at the bottom of Columns C:E.

1. `pullvalue()` works fine if I run it manually.
2. HERE'S THE ISSUE: Setting up a time-driven trigger causes the values to be pasted in at C1:E1 instead of at the bottom of the columns.
3. My suspicion is that `target_range` is breaking down when `Clast` returns a zero value, but I can't figure out why.

What am I missing? Thanks for your help/feedback!

```js
function pullvalue() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Production");
   var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Production");
   var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("N2:P2");
   var Cvals = ss.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
   var Clast = Cvals.filter(String).length;
   var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("C"+(Clast+1)+":E"+(Clast+1))
   source_range.copyTo(target_range, {contentsOnly:true});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify this line:

```
var Cvals = ss.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
```

variable ss return currently activespreadsheet only, but when it runs from a time-driven trigger there is no active sheet, so you need to indicate the sheet, you can use getSheetByName() or getSheets() the line should look like this:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var Cvals = sheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.